# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre una función de valor y una función "Void"?

Tags: c, funciones

tengo una duda ya que recién estoy aprendiendo programación en C y estoy un poco confundido con las funciones de valor y las funciones sin retorno de valor ("Void")

¿En que situaciones en especifico utilizo funciones de valor y en que momento utilizo funciones sin retorno de valor "void"?

Answer (score 1):

las funciones de retornos con valor, especifica un conjunto de instrucciones con el propósito de obtener un resultado y retornarlo a una variable.

```
....
int x;
int a = 5;
int b = 3;
x = funcionSuma(a,b); //x = 8
```

Las funcioes de tipo void, ejecutan las instrucciones sin la necesidad de retornar valores, en programacion c# es muy utilizado para "dibujar" componentes gráficos (nativos o de terceros como devexpress).

¿Cuándo usaras void o retorno de valor?
dependerá tambien la manera o estilo en que diseñe en tus programas, si usas variables globales en c, puedes usar una función void para alterar el valor de dichas variables o sino puedes usar una función que retorne un valor y asignarselo a tu variable global.

> te aconsejo que uses funciones de retorno para "modularizar" tu programita

Comment: cuidado. En C el tipo void ES un tipo. Se prodria valorar como "no definido", de manera que podrias hacer un return de cualquier tipo (int, char,...), y la función que recibe el dato seria la encargada de decidir que tipo de dato es. Se suele utilizar con punteros de tipo void *, de manera que el resultado de esa función es "dinamico"

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, me has ayudado mucho